# MySQL Can't create table (errno: 150) - table has no foreign key

Tags: mysql, runtime-error

1- I know this question has been asked several times. 
2- I read them all 
3- It didn't fix my problem
4- I know it's related to foreign key relationship

I just want to create a table that has no Foreign key but still I get this error

```
Can't create table 'pwp.decision_nodes' (errno: 150)
```

Here is the table create statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `decision_nodes` (
  `id` BIGINT(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `decision_node_id` BIGINT(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY pk_index(`id`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=125 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I even tried

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

and run the create statement but to no avail.

MySQL version

```
'5.5.21-log'
```

I am not exactly sure, but I think there was a table with the same name in the database previously ( long time ago) which was perhaps renamed or dropped. Can that be a hint?

That historical table (renamed or dropped) had foreign key relationships with two other tables  `help_entity` and  `ref_cancer_type`

```
CREATE TABLE `help_entity` (
  `id` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `ref_cancer_type` (
  `id` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `display_order` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Does this prove any point?

Comment: what other tables do you have in the `pwp` database?

Comment: @DJV I've edited my post and all the tables are listed there now

Comment: what I meant was creation queries for those tables. more precisely to only those who are related to `decision_nodes`

Comment: Not related to your question: are you aware that `bigint(45)` does not limit the values you can store in that column? It's only a *hint* for client applications on how wide that column should be displayed.

Comment: I wouldn't say that I am completely familiar with this but I read it a few days ago and was a little confused and a bit surprised as well. But more explanation to this would be appreciated

Comment: @DJV Edited the question. Can you give it a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think some of your other tables have foreign key references to this table you now want to create.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

```
If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign
key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have 
indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error 
number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.
```

Comment: I've modified my question, can you give a look now?

Comment: Can you drop and re-create those two tables, or rename them temporarily to check that if you are able to create decision_nodes -table then?

Comment: On the production, not possible at the moment but I can try later in the day and on local machine I don't get this error altogether which is very strange.

Comment: What does this query give you:

select 
 TABLE_NAME,
 COLUMN_NAME,
 CONSTRAINT_NAME,
 REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
 REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
from 
 information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where
 REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME in ('help_entity', 'ref_cancer_type', 'decision_nodes');

Comment: Here is the result set snapshot of the above query [link](http://s11.postimage.org/gnd33qzcj/resultset.png)

The interesting thing is that I don't have a table named `decision_nodes` when I run SHOW TABLES

Comment: and when I run I get 
    `SELECT * FROM decision_nodes;`
I get this error `Error Code : 1146
    Table 'pwp_test.decision_nodes' doesn't exist`
Which obviously means that the table does not exist

Comment: Do you have access to the filesystemn? Can you see decision_nodes.myi and decision_nodes.frm, decision_nodes.myd etc? And pleas note that in unix-filesystems, database filenames are case sensitive but for example in windows they are not.

Comment: Seems that no such files exists on my Linux system.

Comment: Something is broken. If it is possible, create a dump from your production database. Then import that dump into a new database. Everything should work after that but you need to figure how to fix production. Try google "fix innodb databases" etc ..

Comment: OKay, here is a mistake that I made. In your suggested query I didn't include `constraint_schema = DATABASE()` in the WHERE clause. So when I execute the modified query `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE constraint_schema = DATABASE() AND 
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IN ('help_entity', 'ref_cancer_type', 'decision_nodes'); ` it doesn't show any table named `decision_nodes`. Which means `decision_nodes` does not exist. Is that helpful?